# Are Chasidei Umot haOlam a mixture of pure and impure, or just pure?

Tags: chabad, tanya

It's stated in Lessons in Tanya Ch.1 that Chasidei Umot haOlam emanate from klipat nogah. Klipat nogah contains purity and impurity. Do Chasidei Umot haOlam retain the purity and impurity, or do they just retain the purity?

Comment: What do you mean by purity and impurity?

Comment: Do you assume that the Jews klipat noga soul contains purity and impurity? If so, then why would a non Jewish should be any purer?